# AppleScript do shell script cURL command for Amazon s3

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, applescript

I work exclusively in a Mac OSX environment and I am trying to automate uploading .zip files onto my amazon s3 bucket.

I have been trying the last couple of days and I am really stumped.  I have tried many different variations of what I will post and I always get the same result of errors.  I even tried having my AppleScript call a .sh file and still could not get a result.

I am not going to post my whole code just the part where I am doing the cURL command.  My string that contains my entire cURL command is all in one line because I read that was best for AppleScript to understand.

```
    set objectName to "My\\ Big\\ Test.zip"
    set dateFormatted to do shell script "date -R"
    set s3Bucket to "zipsOnAmazon"
    set fileName to zipFile
    set relativePath to (" " & s3Bucket & "/" & objectName & " ")
    set s3AccessKey to "my-key"
    set s3SecretKey to "my-secret"
    set contentType to "application/octet-stream"
    set stringToSign to "PUT " & contentType & " " & dateFormatted & relativePath & " "

    set signature to "echo -en " & stringToSign & " | openssl sha1 -hmac " & s3SecretKey & " - binary | base64"

    set theBigCommand to "-X PUT -T " & fileName & " \\ -H \"Host: " & s3Bucket & ".s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com \\ -H \"Date: " & dateFormatted & " \\ -H \"Content-Type: " & contentType & " \\ -H \"Authorization: AWS " & s3AccessKey & ":" & signature & " \\ https://" & s3Bucket & ".s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" & objectName & ""

    display dialog ("curl " & theBigCommand & "")


    do shell script ("curl " & theBigCommand & "")
```

So I end up getting two major error messages:

1. > curl: option -0800: is unknown: unknown option '-'
2. > "Unable to open '[https://zipsOnAmazon.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/My Big Test.zip](https://zipsOnAmazon.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/My%20Big%20Test.zip)': No such file or directory"

This error confuses me because I am not trying to open that file I am trying to add it to that path with that name.  But every single cURL example I see has the bucket and the objectName there.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the actual curl command that gets created? (That is, the text displayed in your dialog.)

Comment: As for error 2, it's probably trying to open the url as a *local* file, and getting confused. Seeing that command line would *definitely* clear that up.

Comment: "My string that contains my entire cURL command is all in one line because I read that was best for AppleScript to understand."  Nonsense.  On a different matter, have you tried making sure the `curl` command physically works in *Terminal* ?

Comment: OK, I've just done a copy-n-paste of your code into *Script Editor* and there are a few syntax errors in your shell command.  Give me a bit and I'll clean it up and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had a bunch of syntactical errors in it, which was why the shell command was throwing errors.  Most weren't really much more than typos, undoubtedly because you chose to write out your command string in one long line, and couldn't keep track of where your opening and closing quotes were falling.  But there were one or two bigger anomalies.

> My string that contains my entire cURL command is all in one line because I read that was best for AppleScript to understand.

Nope.

AppleScript doesn't care one way or the other.  It's certainly more difficult for a human to understand, but what I did was to send the command string to the clipboard in AppleScript (this parses the escaped characters), and then paste it into *Terminal* to see what's what.

I'll paste the new modified code and try and walk you through the changes:

```
    set objectName to "My Big Test.zip"
```

I removed your manual escaping of the spaces, because AppleScript has a means by which it can escape strings and it does this very well, esuring the resulting form will be interpreted corrected by a shell command.

```
    set dateFormatted to do shell script "date -R"
    set s3Bucket to "zipsOnAmazon"
    set fileName to zipFile
    set relativePath to (" " & s3Bucket & "/" & objectName & " ")
    set s3AccessKey to "my-key"
    set s3SecretKey to "my-secret"
    set contentType to "application/octet-stream"
    set stringToSign to "PUT " & contentType & " " & dateFormatted & relativePath & " "
```

I removed the end components of your command string and used them to create a variable that contains the URL for `curl`.  Within this concatenation is the now-unescaped `objectName`.  Instead, we'll get AppleScript to treat the entire URL for us, rather than just one individual component.

```
    set OPTURL to "https://" & s3Bucket & ".s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" & objectName
```

This was one of the big errors.  You incorporated what is now the `signatureCommand` string into your `curl` command string.  It *is* possible to do this, but a) you did it wrongly; and b) there's no point making it more difficult for yourself than is necessary.

The `echo` command through to the `openssl` and `base64` commands are best handled first, in order to obtain the signature.

This is also where your first error was thrown (`curl: option -0800: is unknown: unknown option '-'`): it was simple typo, where you wrote `- binary` instead of `-binary`,

```
    set signatureCommand to "echo -en " & stringToSign & ¬
        " | openssl sha1 -hmac " & s3SecretKey & " -binary | base64"

    set signature to do shell script signatureCommand
```

The `signature` variable is now, itself, the result of a shell command.  But it's now the correct result.

Next, I've formatted the string over multiple lines to make it more human-readable.  AppleScript is very content with this.  I removed all the myriad backslashes you had all over the place—they were redundant.  I also exchanged your backslashed-double quotes for single quotes.  Either are acceptable, but the latter made it much more readable without confusing where double-quotes were starting and ending.

After I lined up the headers, it was clear that losing track of double-quotes was the issue: your headers would have an opening quotation mark, but not have a closing one.  Therefore, the next opening mark was taken to be the previous closing mark, which upset all the text strings inside the `curl` command.

Here's the correctly-formatted declaration:

```
    set theBigCommand to "-X PUT -T " & quoted form of fileName & ¬
        " -H 'Host: " & s3Bucket & ".s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'" & ¬
        " -H 'Date: " & dateFormatted & "'" & ¬
        " -H 'Content-Type: " & contentType & "'" & ¬
        " -H 'Authorization: AWS " & s3AccessKey & ":" & signature & "'" & ¬
        " --url " & quoted form of OPTURL
```

Note the use of a proprety called the `quoted form of` a string.  This is the way AppleScript escapes strings for using them inside shell commands.  Most of the time, it's a simple case of letting AppleScript surround a string in single quotes, which is all that was required for the URL.  I also applied this formatting to the `fileName` variable, which can now have spaces in its names without bother.

```
    display dialog ("curl " & theBigCommand & "")

    do shell script ("curl " & theBigCommand & "")
```

I ran the `curl` command and received this output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>HttpVersionNotSupported</Code><Message>The HTTP version specified is not supported.</Message><RequestId>C413DB82E1D5502B</RequestId><HostId>p4nc6t/hwGE5l29+y3wR/VUgStZqtjMi9tem/0yl3zSCx1FyeJ/8FZW7ZFEZPYVPxkMF9wm54IxOaPGeVcprpGBrc1suEZKU</HostId></Error>`

which is partly expected, given I was using duff placeholders for real filenames and access tokens.  I'm not sure how to interpret the message regarding the HTTP version not being supported.  I suggest you use your actual data to give the code a try and see what the server returns back to you.  But this, at least, confirms that the `curl` command is now working appropriately.

---

If you do end up getting stuck on the server side of things, I came across [this PHP script](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/24-38656-154166-2848/s3-put-example.phps) that appears to accomplish the same task as you're attempting to do.  I don't know whether or not you're familiar with PHP; you don't really need to be, as it's quite straightforward to read and interpret what's happening.

If your script fails, you could try mimicking the steps in that PHP script and creating the appropriate AppleScript commands to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  This was very useful and i learned a lot.

Comment: I have double checked that I have the correct key and secret and I get the same error as you  Can’t get result of "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Error><Code>HttpVersionNotSupported</Code><Message>The HTTP version specified is not supported.    I believe from the research I have done it is because the filename has spaces in it and needs to be url encoded

Comment: I thought you might.  I noticed when comparing your AppleScript to the PHP script I linked to, that there were some parameters missing.  Have a look through the PHP code and check what information it collects for the `curl`  process versus what you’ve collected.  Also double check you’ve constructed your signature correctly.  If you’re still stuck, it might be an  idea to post another question regarding construction of `curl` headers and data values.  Or, if you’re fed up, you could just used the PHP script, passing it to the `php` function in *Terminal* or through `do shell script`.

Comment: I think you’re right about the url encoding.  Possibly applicable to the signature as well.

Comment: Yes I encoded my "zipfile" properly since it had spaces in its name but now i am having the same issue with the signature and no matter what kind of encoding i do i still get an error: "<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</"  I will need to do research on how to setup the signature properly then

Comment: I would suggest posting another question and asking for help with this, as it’s now a separate issue.  I’m sure someone will know what the problem is.

Comment: Sounds good I will test first and if i get stumped I will post another question.  Thank you so much for the help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I ended up using a different PHP script that worked automatically when I added the correct variables and then ran that php script from my AppleScript.  https://www.h3xed.com/programming/simple-php-code-for-uploading-a-file-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket