# cURL to AWS S3 using AppleScript

Tags: amazon-s3, applescript

I'm using AppleScript and shell to curl files from my local system to an AWS S3 bucket. I'm able to accomplish this calling a bash script from AppleScript, but when I try to use strictly AppleScript I get a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error from AWS.

Anybody see what might be wrong?

There is an existing thread on this where the OP encountered the same problem then finally gave up on this method and used PHP.

[AppleScript do shell script cURL command for Amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573045/applescript-do-shell-script-curl-command-for-amazon-s3)

My code:

```
--File info
set filePath to "/Volumes/MyFolder"
set fileName to "001.jpg"

--AWS Info
set awsRegion to "s3-us-west-1"
set bucketName to "mybucketname"
set awsPath to "mysubfolder"
set s3key to "myawskey"
set s3secret to "myawssecretkey"

--Build cannonical request
set acl to "x-amz-acl:public-read"
set contentType to "application/octet-stream"
set storageType to "x-amz-storage-class:STANDARD"
--set theDate to do shell script "date '+%a, %d %b %Y %T %z'"
set theDate to do shell script "date -R"
set connonicalString to "PUT\\n\\n" & contentType & "\\n" & theDate & "\\n" & acl & "\\n" & storageType & "\\n/" & bucketName & "/" & awsPath & "/" & fileName
set signatureCommand to "echo -en " & connonicalString & " | openssl sha1 -hmac " & s3secret & " -binary | base64"
set signature to do shell script signatureCommand

--Build the curl command
set curlCommand to "curl -s -X PUT"
set sourcePath to " -T " & filePath & "/" & fileName
set header01 to " -H 'Host: " & bucketName & "." & awsRegion & ".amazonaws.com'"
set header02 to " -H 'Date: " & theDate & "'"
set header03 to " -H 'Content-Type: " & contentType & "'"
set header04 to " -H '" & storageType & "'"
set header05 to " -H '" & acl & "'"
set header06 to " -H 'Authorization: AWS " & s3key & ":" & signature & "'"
set targetPath to " https://" & bucketName & "." & awsRegion & ".amazonaws.com/" & awsPath & "/" & fileName

set shellCommand to curlCommand & sourcePath & header01 & header02 & header03 & header04 & header05 & header06 & targetPath

--Run the script
do shell script shellCommand
```

Here is the error:

`SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method....

Comment: Why not just write it as a `bash` script without using AppleScript?  Also, when requesting help with debugging, the question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The file upload will be initiated from Filemaker so an AppleScript is necessary regardless of whether a bash script is used. Not sure if I'll run into permissions issues making the bash script executable in a managed environment so I thought I'd try and make the whole process work in AS. Also makes the script more portable.

Comment: Not sure how my post doesn't conform with the guidelines. Obviously I had to remove my AWS login info from the sample, otherwise that's the relevant part of the code. Appreciate any input

Comment: I do not have an AWS account, so I cannot test the code sample you've provided as is and therefore IMO is does not conform to MCVE.  That said, since the error is occurring with what is says, I'd suggest you look in the Event viewer and or Log History in Script Editor to see what's going on and compare the command being run in the `do shell script` command and make sure it matches what you'd manually pass as a command in Terminal. Then go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The signature string is different every time the script is run whether it's in bash or AS because of the date being hashed so it's not possible to do an exact one to one comparison of the curl command as generated in bash and the curl command as generated in AS, which of course is where the error resides

Comment: If you can run the command by manually building it in Terminal and it works, but it doesn't in AppleScript then look elsewhere in comparing what the command looks like when done in AppleScript vs. in Terminal and make sure what `do shell script` executes is the same structure down to all the other elements, spaces and quotes, etc. where appropriate to avoid globbing and word splitting in the command run in the `do shell script`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you cite is due to the shell being used by applescript:  it's /bin/sh
but your terminal emulator is probably using BASH (/bin/bash).
Therein, the `echo` used in /bin/sh seems not to accept switches!
i.e., "-en " got rolled into what becomes applescript variable |connonicalString|

Either substitute for `echo -en` with `printf %s` (no trailing space!) or use heredoc syntax for variable signatureCommand for its use in 
 `do shell script signatureCommand`

```
set signatureCommand to "/bin/bash <<EOF
echo -en " & connonicalString & " | openssl sha1 -hmac " & s3secret & " -binary | base64
EOF"
```

Compare this output done in a terminal window running BASH:

```
Last login: Tue Mar 24 12:17:22 on ttys003
mylocal:~ myself$ echo -en PUT\n\napplication/octet-stream\nTue, 24 Mar 2020 16:07:09 -0400\nx-amz-acl:public-read\nx-amz-storage-class:STANDARD\n/mybucketname/mysubfolder/001.jpg | openssl sha1 -hmac myawssecretkey -binary | base64

CpUNJTkp6i1ocERz7PQ+Q/m5rYI=
```

With this output done in a terminal window running /bin/sh:

```
mylocal:~ myself$ /bin/sh
mylocal:~ myself$ echo -en PUT\n\napplication/octet-stream\nTue, 24 Mar 2020 16:07:09 -0400\nx-amz-acl:public-read\nx-amz-storage-class:STANDARD\n/mybucketname/mysubfolder/001.jpg | openssl sha1 -hmac myawssecretkey -binary | base64

Wy1tNXiDmDsdlm/sBDDYCoc0kik=
```

Then observe what is the output in Script Editor using its default /bin/sh:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "date -R"
        --> "Tue, 24 Mar 2020 16:07:09 -0400"
    do shell script "echo -en PUT\\n\\napplication/octet-stream\\nTue, 24 Mar 2020 16:07:09 -0400\\nx-amz-acl:public-read\\nx-amz-storage-class:STANDARD\\n/mybucketname/mysubfolder/001.jpg | openssl sha1 -hmac myawssecretkey -binary | base64"
        --> "Wy1tNXiDmDsdlm/sBDDYCoc0kik="
end tell
Result:
"Wy1tNXiDmDsdlm/sBDDYCoc0kik="
```

and then forcing it to use /bin/bash:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "date -R"
        --> "Tue, 24 Mar 2020 16:46:47 -0400"
    do shell script "/bin/bash <<EOF
echo -en PUT\\n\\napplication/octet-stream\\nTue, 24 Mar 2020 16:07:09 -0400\\nx-amz-acl:public-read\\nx-amz-storage-class:STANDARD\\n/mybucketname/mysubfolder/001.jpg | openssl sha1 -hmac myawssecretkey -binary | base64
EOF"
        --> "CpUNJTkp6i1ocERz7PQ+Q/m5rYI="
end tell
Result:
"CpUNJTkp6i1ocERz7PQ+Q/m5rYI="
```